# Spring DI NullPointerException @Autowired fail

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception, vaadin

My name Daniel and I'm a beginner of Java and WebApplications.
I have a question, because i have a problem with NullPointerException.

I learn Spring Dependency Injection. I made mistake but I can't find it.
Thank You for help.

```
public class EmailServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    @Override
    public String getMessage(String messageName) {
        return "EMAIL_SERVICE";
    }
}

public class NotifyServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    @Override
    public String getMessage(String messageName) {
        return "NOTIFY_SERVICE";
    }
}

@Component
public interface MessageService {
    public String getMessage(String messageName);
}

@Configuration
public class DIConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MessageService getMessageService(){
        return new NotifyServiceImpl();
    }
}


//vaadin init first class    
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(DIConfiguration.class);
        context.refresh();
        MessageService message = context.getBean(MessageService.class);

        Notification.show(message.getMessage("dfsa"));
//it works



        //context.close();
//different class 
//it doesn't work
@Autowired
    private MessageService messages;

Notification.show(messages.getMessage("first"));
```

//stack trace//

```
    /home/daniel/dev/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/bin/catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/daniel/.IntelliJIdea13/system/tomcat/Unnamed_MyProject
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/daniel/dev/apache-tomcat-8.0.3
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/daniel/dev/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/daniel/dev/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/daniel/dev/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
[2014-10-21 04:05:04,571] Artifact MyProject:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.150 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /home/daniel/dev/idea-IU-135.1289/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.455 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.472 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.476 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.478 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.478 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 632 ms
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.505 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.505 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.3
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.515 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.521 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.522 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 43 ms
Connected to server
[2014-10-21 04:05:05,687] Artifact MyProject:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
21-Oct-2014 16:05:05.769 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
paź 21, 2014 4:05:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@7846684d]
[2014-10-21 04:05:08,836] Artifact MyProject:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2014-10-21 04:05:08,836] Artifact MyProject:war exploded: Deploy took 3 149 milliseconds
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration checkProductionMode
WARNING: 
=================================================================
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
Add productionMode=true to web.xml to disable debug features.
To show debug window, add ?debug to your application URL.
=================================================================
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addAtmosphereHandler
INFO: Installed AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler$1 mapped to context-path: /
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addAtmosphereHandler
INFO: Installed the following AtmosphereInterceptor mapped to AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler$1
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework doInitParams
WARNING: SessionSupport error. Make sure you define org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport as a listener in web.xml instead
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework autoConfigureService
INFO: Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor configure
INFO: AnnotationProcessor class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$ServletContainerInitializerAnnotationProcessor being used
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor fallbackToManualAnnotatedClasses
WARNING: Unable to detect annotations. Application may fail to deploy.
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework autoDetectWebSocketHandler
INFO: Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework initWebSocket
INFO: Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFO: Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptor
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor : Heartbeat Interceptor Support
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFO: Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Shared ExecutorService supported: true
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Messaging Thread Pool Size: Unlimited
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: HttpSession supported: true
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket running under container: Apache Tomcat/8.0.3 using javax.servlet/3.0
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere Framework 2.1.2.vaadin5 started.
paź 21, 2014 4:05:09 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework interceptor
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
16:05:10.740 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
16:05:10.746 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:05:10.748 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:05:10.748 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
16:05:10.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
16:05:10.797 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2a521c9d: startup date [Tue Oct 21 16:05:10 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
16:05:10.798 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Bean factory for org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2a521c9d: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@167180b0: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,DIConfiguration]; root of factory hierarchy
16:05:10.812 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.813 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.834 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:05:10.837 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.873 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method pl.infotower.spring.DIConfiguration.getMessageService()
16:05:10.982 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced pl.infotower.spring.DIConfiguration; enhanced class name is: pl.infotower.spring.DIConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5075f3a1
16:05:10.982 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'DIConfiguration' existing class name 'pl.infotower.spring.DIConfiguration' with enhanced class name 'pl.infotower.spring.DIConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5075f3a1'
16:05:10.985 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.986 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.987 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:05:10.988 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.988 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.988 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.989 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:05:10.989 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.989 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.989 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.996 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:05:10.996 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:10.996 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
16:05:10.996 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
16:05:10.996 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:05:10.996 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
16:05:10.996 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
16:05:10.997 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
16:05:10.997 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:05:10.997 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
16:05:11.003 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@603be86e]
16:05:11.007 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@7c485f83]
16:05:11.009 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@167180b0: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,DIConfiguration,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,getMessageService]; root of factory hierarchy
16:05:11.010 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:11.010 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:11.010 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:11.010 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
16:05:11.010 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'DIConfiguration'
16:05:11.010 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'DIConfiguration'
16:05:11.013 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'DIConfiguration' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:05:11.054 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'DIConfiguration'
16:05:11.054 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
16:05:11.054 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
16:05:11.055 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'getMessageService'
16:05:11.055 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'getMessageService'
16:05:11.058 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'DIConfiguration'
16:05:11.095 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'getMessageService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:05:11.099 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'getMessageService'
16:05:11.103 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@56c62d60]
16:05:11.103 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
16:05:11.107 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
16:05:11.107 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
16:05:11.108 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
16:05:11.108 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'getMessageService'
21-Oct-2014 16:05:15.516 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/daniel/dev/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/webapps/manager
paź 21, 2014 4:05:16 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.infotower.views.HelpView$1.buttonClick(HelpView.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:979)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:287)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:180)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:93)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1402)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I use

```
Notification.show(messages.getMessage("first"));
```

throw NullPointerEx.

Comment: please post complete stack trace. It will help with pin pointing exact cause. Also the `@Component` annotation should be applied to class and not on interface

Comment: Obviously there is an error in your `HelpView` class (first inner class) due to this line of error stack: `pl.infotower.views.HelpView$1.buttonClick(HelpView.java:52)`. Can you please show us the code of this class, especially all things concernig line 52?

Comment: Thank you for providing the requested code. Just a thought on the policy: normally it would be better to place such additional stuff directly to the question, as it isn't an answer to the question. Otherwise people coming around searching for an answer could be irritated. If you want to, you can even now use the **edit** link and remove the "answer" after moving the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**Vaadin objects natively are not controlled by the Spring container**. Therefore the `@Autowired` annotation used in the `HelpView` class isn't honoured. To get the example to work you need to make some integration efforts. There are a couple of different approaches to be found in blogs and tutorials on the internet.

**One approach working** without changing your sample code to much is using @AspectJ. I'll explain it using Maven as management tool. Please adopt the steps as needed if you manage your project in another way.

**Main point**: annotate the vaadin classes (or any other non-spring classes as well) in need of autowiring/injection capability with `@Configurable`. Do not forget adding the `<context:spring-configured />` entry in application context file shown further down. Thus AspectJ will do all the magic needed:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;

@Configured
public class HelpView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messages;

    ...
```

**Get AspectJ to work**

AspectJ itself will need some configuration. First of all the **AspectJ compiler** must be invoked. With Maven you achieve that by using the following plugin (copy the xml to your pom.xml as child of `<plugins />`):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Secondly, **AspectJ runtime** and **Spring's AOP ressources** are needed. Copy the following to your Maven `<dependencies />` element (in pom.xml):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Lastly you need a configuration entry in the **applications context** file (Bean.xml, root-context.xml, applicationContext.xml, or whatever the name of your beans declaration xml file is).

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured />
```

**Versions**
The version numbers I've chosen work in my environment together well. Maybe one has to change them accordingly to his or her environment.

Answer (score 0):

I now that error is in HelpView, but i don't now what is the reason.

```
package pl.xxx.views;


import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.label.ContentMode;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Notification;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import pl.xxx.data.ExampleUtil;
import pl.xxx.spring.di.MessageService;
import pl.xxx.models.CalculatorModel;
import pl.xxx.ui.MainMenuComponent;
import pl.xxx.presenters.CalculatorPresenter;


public class HelpView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messages;

    public HelpView() {
        setSizeFull();
        setSpacing(true);
        addComponent(new MainMenuComponent());
        addComponent(headingLabel());
        addComponent(someText());
        addComponent(redirectButton());
        addComponent(calculator());
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        Notification.show("Showing view: Help!");
    }

    private Label headingLabel() {
        return new Label("Help");
    }

    private Label someText() {
        Label label = new Label(ExampleUtil.lorem);
        label.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
        return label;
    }

    private Button redirectButton(){
        Button button  = new Button("Calculator", new Button.ClickListener(){
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event){
            Notification.show(messages.getMessage("first"));
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    private CalculatorViewImpl calculator() {
        CalculatorModel model = new CalculatorModel();
        CalculatorViewImpl view = new CalculatorViewImpl();
        new CalculatorPresenter(model, view);
        return view;
    }

}
```